# A Function in C to reduce Rational number using Structures

Tags: c, data-structures

```
#define TRUE 1

#define FALSE 2

struct rational{         
    int numerator;    
    int denominator;    
}       
void reduce(struct rational *inrat,struct rational *outrat)    
{    
    int a,b,rem;        
    if(inrat->numerator>inrat->denominator)      
    {   
        a=intrat->numerator;
        b=inrat_>denominator;    
    }        
    else    
    {    
        b=intrat->numerator;
        a=intrat->denominator;
    }
    while(b!=0)
    {
        rem=a%b;
        a=b;
        b=rem;
    }
    outrat->numerator/=a;      
    outrat->denominator/=a;     
}
```

Ok,this a code to reduce a rational number.  It's based on Euclid's algorithm.
My question is what's the use of the pointer to the structure `outrat` ,if all the data is stored in the variables through `intrat` (in the main function, of course).
Why have used the statement `outrat->numerator/=a; outrat->denominator/=a;`
if the actual values are manipulated through `intrat` pointer, why is `outrat` used?

Comment: Wow.  This is remarkably hard to read.  Could you please take a few minutes to review the formatting guidelines and fix this so we can read it?

Comment: `#define TRUE 1 #define FALSE 2` *::fights off desire to gorge own eyes out::* Why would you do that? C supplies a built in interpretation of 0 -> false, all other values -> true. Breaking that will only confuse programers who come after you. Including your future self.

Comment: @dmckee based on the question I'd guess this isn't user's code, which is even more scary.  I took the liberty of formatting it a bit, since user is new here.  First one's free :)

Comment: `#define TRUE 1

#define FALSE 2` Where's your god now?

Comment: @JoeFish OK, I'll buy that. User1112415 gets a pass, but this means that someone who *really* should have known better is responsible...

Comment: It seems like there have been several 'reduce rational number' questions the past few days.  Must be a popular homework problem.

Comment: @JoeFish Please make it clear to me that,the values(of numerator and denominator)stored by intrat and outrat are same or not? and Thank you very much for the editting,I am totally new here.This is in the book by Tannenbaum for Data Structures.

Comment: @Karanv.10111, I can't be sure but it looks like the intent of the code is that `inrat` and `outrat` are the same when called.  When the function returns, `outrat` contains the reduced real number, and `inrat` remains unchanged.  But your book's text should have more information.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about the algorithm, but looking at the code, `inrat` is the input and `outrat` is the output rational number.

The values are **not** manipulated through `inrat`.  `inrat`'s values are used to calculate a divisor, which is then applied to `outrat`.  So it's `outrat`'s values that are actually manipulated.

Really the function should have been declared with `inrat` as `const` for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the the C++ code for reducing rational number, try same logic in C:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct rational {
       int numerator;
       int denominator;
};
/*struct rational *inputrational  : Actual rational number to be reduced
struct rational *outputrational : Variable to store the rational number in its lowest form */
void reduce(struct rational *inputrational, struct rational *outputrational) {
    //Write your solution code below this line
    int n,m,i=2,min;
     n=inputrational->numerator;
     m=inputrational->denominator;
     min=n>m?m:n;
     for(i=m;i>0;i--){
          if(n%i==0 && m%i==0){
             n=n/i;
            m=m/i;
            break;
            }
        }

    outputrational->numerator=n;
    outputrational->denominator=m;


  }

int main(){
    rational n1,s1;
    n1.numerator=13;
    n1.denominator=6;
    reduce(&n1,&s1);
     cout<<s1.numerator<<" "<<s1.denominator;
}
```